# Can a single SCVMM Self-Service Portal instance manage VMs on multiple hosts?

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2, scvmm

I have two servers, both running Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise with Hyper-V. They both have a number of VMs on them. ServerA also has SCVMM 2008 R2 installed, and the SCVMM Self-Service Portal. I can see the VMs for ServerA on the Self-Service Portal but can't see any way of viewing the VMs on ServerB on the same portal. Is this possible? I'd prefer to only install SCVMM on ServerA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

The VMs on ServerB didn't have an owner set, so didn't show up. Assign all VMs an owner and they will all be listed in the SCVMM Self-Service Portal.